# Name not defined in type annotation

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I'm currently working on creating a python linear algebra module for fun and for practice with the language. I recently tried to add type annotations to the module, as such:

```
class Vector:
     # Various irrelevant implementation details
     def __add__(self, other: Vector) -> Vector:
        # More implementation details....
```

However, when I try to import this, it spits out a `NameError: Name 'Vector' is not defined`. I acknowledge that this question has already been answered, in a form, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461035/function-annotation-in-python-3-get-name-not-defined-error), but it doesn't seem to wholly provide an answer for my situation.

What I'd like to know:

- I've defined the class literally in this file. Why does it say the name isn't defined?
- How do I define `Vector` in such a way that it can be used for annotations (as a `type`)?

Comment: Please keep your post limited to **one** question per post. You have 2 distinct questions in here, one about your circular dependency (methods of the class depending on the class before it has been created), and about the difference between a type and a class. The latter is a duplicate.

Comment: See [Class vs. Type in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35958961) for the part of the question I've removed from your post.

Comment: Sorry. I thought the type question was relevant to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You have a forward declaration; functions (to be bound as methods) are created *before* the class is, so the name `Vector` doesn't yet exist. Only when all of the class body has been executed, can Python create the `class` object and bind the name `Vector` to it.

Simply use a string with the name instead:

```
class Vector:
     # Various irrelevant implementation details
     def __add__(self, other: 'Vector') -> 'Vector':
        # More implementation details....
```

This doesn't affect how your IDE sees the declaration; strings are looked up once the whole module is loaded, and are resolved as a valid Python expression in the current context. Since the class `Vector` exists once the whole module is loaded, the string `'Vector'` can properly be converted to the class object.

Also see the [specification on forward references](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references):

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.
>
> [...]
>
> The string literal should contain a valid Python expression [...] and it should evaluate without errors once the module has been fully loaded.

As of Python 3.7 you can make all annotations in a given module behave like forward annotations (without enclosing them in a string literal), by adding the `from __future__ import annotations` directive at the top of the module. It was originally planned for this to be the default in Python 3.10 and up, but this decision has now been deferred indefinitely. See [PEP 563 -- *Postponed Evaluation of Annotations*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) for details. Note that *outside* of annotations you may still need to use forward reference syntax (string literals), e.g. in a type alias (which is a regular variable assignment as far as Python is concerned).

Answer (score 56):

If you are using *Python 3.7* and above. Take a look at [Postponed evaluation of annotations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-563-postponed-evaluation-of-annotations)

Since Python 3.7, it will be allowed, just add:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

And also note that

> It will become the default in Python 3.10.

Comment: This is interesting to note. I'm going to leave the answer as-is because it works for all 3.x versions (or at least, more 3.x versions than the `import annotations` solution), but I'm still glad you posted this here.

Comment: Make sure this you enter this line as the first line in your module.

Comment: @VladBezden Sure, as pep8 suggests: imports at the top of file and __future__ ones go first.

Comment: For Python 3.6, I get error `future feature annotations is not defined`

Comment: @ShitalShah yes, because it's a feature of **Python 3.7.x - 4.0** as it was said in the answer.

Comment: this seems like a more canonical solution.