# How to declare operation with parameter of Outer class type in nested class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Surprisingly this simple program doesn't work and I wonder why, and whether it is possible to make it working (without removing parameter type specification):

```
class Outer:
    class Inner:
        def __init__(self, parent: Outer):
            self.parent = parent
```

It complains that Outer is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that you rarely actually need to nest classes in Python. There is probably another approach to whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: Someone posted and removed this link (so I've added it again) http://stackoverflow.com/a/36286947/2314391

Comment: @Will the auto-comment was removed because this question has been closed as a duplicate of that one, so the link is now in the banner at the top of the page. There's no need to add it again.

Comment: Ok, Thank You all