# How to use type hinting in Python when loading objects

Tags: python, pickle, type-hinting, code-hinting

How can I alert python of the return type of a pickle.load() command within a class where load() command returns an object of the class.

I had hoped the straight-forward

```
class myClass:

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, filename) -> myClass:
        with open(filename,'rb') as f:
            return pickle.load(f)
```

would work, but python complains that myClass is not defined.

I'd like for python to know the class type for code completion, etc.

Comment: In Python 3.7 this will be a valid syntax: https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-563-postponed-evaluation-of-annotations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name not defined in type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286894/name-not-defined-in-type-annotation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I specify that the return type of a method is the same as the class itself in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-specify-that-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-the-same-as-the-class-itsel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're probably aware, at the time when you define the classmethod, `myClass` doesn't yet exist, so you can't reference it directly.

The prescribed alternative is to use string representations of the object.  It's not perfect, but at the end of the day type-hinting is not a strict means of enforcement; it's just an informal hint.

From [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references):

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that
>   definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.

```
class myClass:
    @classmethod
    def load(cls, filename) -> 'myClass':
        with open(filename,'rb') as f:
            return pickle.load(f)
```

In fact, there's an example very similar to yours from that PEP:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, left: 'Tree', right: 'Tree'):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```