# Interdependence of 2 classes with type hint in Python

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

I want to defined 2 classes and use type hints in Python 3.4+, but with some dependence between them.

This is the code I have

```
class Child():
    def __init__(self, name:str, parent:Parent) -> None:
        """Create a child

        Args:
            name (str): Name of the child
            parent (Parent): Parent (object)
        """
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        parent.give_life(self)


class Parent():
    def __init__(self, name:str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.Children = []  # type: List[Child]

    def give_life(self, child:Child) -> None:
        self.Children.append(child)
```

and the error returned by `pylint`:

> E0601:Using variable 'Parent' before assignment

How can I hint the type of `parent` argument of initialization function of `Child` class?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name not defined in type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286894/name-not-defined-in-type-annotation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a case of forward declaration.

To make it work, you can us string `'Parent'` instead of class Name `Parent` for the function `Child.__init__` (and optionally `Parent.give_life` to make it symmetric).

The resulting code is the following:

```
class Child():
    def __init__(self, name:str, parent:'Parent') -> None:
        """Create a child

        Args:
            name (str): Name of the child
            parent (Parent): Parent (object)
        """
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        parent.give_life(self)


class Parent():
    def __init__(self, name:str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.Children = []  # type: List[Child]

    def give_life(self, child:'Child') -> None:
        self.Children.append(child)
```