# How to tell Sublime this function return will return that class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I have some codes like this:

```
@zhihu.log_attr
@zhihu.iter_factory('voters')
def voters(x):
    from .People import People
    return People(x)
```

But the IDE ...
[Imgur Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vAMw.png)

So I try this way:

```
@zhihu.log_attr
@zhihu.iter_factory('voters')
def voters(x)->People:
    from .People import People
    return People(x)
```

But it don't works.

```
NameError: name 'People' is not defined
```

Comment: Just as a side note, Sublime isn't an IDE; it's a text editor. It uses an external Python interpreter to run your program, so if you see errors in your code it's unlikely that Sublime has anything to do with it (unless there are special steps to be taken before running your program like activating a virtual environment or something).

Answer (score 0):

If the return type is not defined when you're defining your function you can specify the return type as a string:

```
@zhihu.log_attr
@zhihu.iter_factory('voters')
def voters(x) -> 'People':
    from .People import People
    return People(x)
```

PyCharm is smart enough to use the above to look up object attributes, hopefully Sublime is too.

**Edit**: a more detailed answer here: [Name not defined in type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286894/name-not-defined-in-type-annotation)

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, this 'People' class is a subclass of this class and be defined in another file. I have tried your way, but it don't work. Nothing happened

Comment: It may be that Sublime doesn't recognise the type hint. Have you tried another IDE such as PyCharm?

Comment: You also probably want to avoid naming both the module and the class exactly the same as it's confusing and unconventional. Typically the module name is lowercase, e.g. `from people import People`.

Comment: Thanks for your patiention.

Comment: No worries. Patiention is my new favourite word.

Comment: Hi, I think I find the question.

Comment: `@zhihu.iter_factory('voters')` will return a complex  iterator, like this:

Comment: def iter_factory(url_function_name, method=json):  
    def decorate(deal_function):   
            def iter_function(count=-1, start=1, page=-1)->Iterable[People()]:
            ...