# Python 3 typing annotation and parent-child design

Tags: python, parent-child, typing

I am writing some Python code where I have to use parent-child design like this:

```
from typing import List


class Parent(object):

    def add_children(self, child: List[Child]):
        """Do something here"""


class Child(object):

    def set_parent(self, parent: Parent):
        """Do something here"""
```

But Python raises a `NameError` and complains that the `Child` class was not defined. This is logical because it is under the `Parent` class.

Is there something like "Forward declaration" in C++ to handle problems like this or is there is some other way? I tried to Google it with no success.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a circular dependency problem.

When your code is run and the `Parent` class is encountered, it looks for the `Child` class definition, but it is defined afterwards so it cannot find it and throws the error!

If you swap the two definitions, when your code is run and the `Child` class is encountered, it looks for the `Parent` class definition, but it is defined afterwards so it cannot find it and throws the error!

To resolve this you have to use a string in the name as identified in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286894/name-not-defined-in-type-annotation/36286947#36286947) and the issue will be resolved

```
 def add_children(self, child: "List[Child]"):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a string specifying the name:

```py
def add_children(self, child: "List[Child]"):
```

For further explanation, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36286947/695377).